# Where and how should I initialize service which is used for sending requests like HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, architecture

I am using Google Vision API and its C# library.

I want to understand where should I initialize `ImageAnnotatorClient` and how should I register `GoogleVisionApiService`.
`ImageAnnotatorClient` is used for sending images to the Google Vision API, like this `_imageAnnotatorClient.DetectSafeSearchAsync(image)`

First way - register service as Singleton and initialize ImageAnnotatorClient in the constructor

```
public class GoogleVisionApiService : IGoogleVisionApiService
{
    private readonly IGoogleCredentialFactory _googleCredentialFactory;
    private readonly ImageAnnotatorClient _imageAnnotatorClient;

    public GoogleVisionApiService(IGoogleCredentialFactory googleCredentialFactory) 
    {
        _googleCredentialFactory = googleCredentialFactory;
        _imageAnnotatorClient = InitializeClient();
    }

    private ImageAnnotatorClient InitializeClient()
    {
        var googleCredential = _googleCredentialFactory.GetGoogleCredentialAsync().Result;
        var credential = googleCredential.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
        
        var imageAnnotatorClientBuilder = new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder
        {
            Credential = credential
        };

        var imageAnnotatorClient = imageAnnotatorClientBuilder.Build();
        
        return imageAnnotatorClient;
    }
    
    public async Task<SafeSearchAnnotation> GetSafeSearchAnnotationAsync(string imageBase64)
    {        
        var image = Image.FromBytes(Convert.FromBase64String(requestImage));

        var labels = await _imageAnnotatorClient.DetectSafeSearchAsync(image);

        return labels;
    }
}
```

Second way is to register service as Transient and initialize client every time service is called

```
public class GoogleVisionApiService : IGoogleVisionApiService
{
    private readonly IGoogleCredentialFactory _googleCredentialFactory;

    public GoogleVisionApiService(IGoogleCredentialFactory googleCredentialFactory) 
    {
        _googleCredentialFactory = googleCredentialFactory;
    }

    public async Task<SafeSearchAnnotation> GetSafeSearchAnnotationAsync(string imageBase64)
    {      
        var googleCredential = await _googleCredentialFactory.GetGoogleCredentialAsync();
        var credential = googleCredential.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
        
        var imageAnnotatorClientBuilder = new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder
        {
            Credential = credential
        };

        var imageAnnotatorClient = await imageAnnotatorClientBuilder.BuildAsync();  

        var image = Image.FromBytes(Convert.FromBase64String(requestImage));

        var labels = await _imageAnnotatorClient.DetectSafeSearchAsync(image);

        return labels;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your credentials coming from, and do you expect them to be the same for every request? Ideally, you should only create a single client - and now we have better support for DI, so it should be quite easy, but I'll need to know more about where your credentials are coming from to be specific in an answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Credentials are saved in the Azure KV, I am getting them via API request. But they are cached after the first request

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's best to create a single RPC client if you can.

In your specific case, I'd suggest using the (relatively new) DI-friendly extension methods in the Google client libraries. Then your `GoogleVisionApiService` can just accept an `ImageAnnotatorClient`.

```cs
// Wherever you're configuring services
services
    // Make sure everything uses the right credential
    .AddSingleton<GoogleCredential>(provider => /* code to fetch credential */)
    // Note: this is for .NET 6 and .NET Core 3.1. Without this line, the client builder
    // will use the "right" adapter for the environment, but won't be able to hook gRPC
    // logging up with the DI's logging configuration
    .AddGrpcNetClientAdapter()
    .AddImageAnnotatorClient();
```

See the [client lifecycle docs](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/help/client-lifecycle) for more information.

Comment: This was is great,but I cant inject `GoogleCredential` like this (due to some reasons). It there any other way how can I do it?

Comment: @user12398280: Without knowing why you can't inject the `GoogleCredential`, it's hard to say - anything I might suggest could be invalid for exactly the same reason. You could potentially inject something which then lazily instantiates the `ImageAnnotatorClient` based on the credential, but we don't really know. Given your first code snippet, I suspect you *could* inject the `GoogleCredential` as `services.AddSingleton(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IGoogleCredentialFactory>().GetGoogleCredential());` or similar.